# Data from session is not added but it is recreated while testing with client side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session

This thing works on server side fine for me, session successfully adds data in a cart as it should. But on client side (I'm using axios) the session is constantly being recreated. By recreating the data I mean for example when I try to add more items in cart, whole the time quantity is still 1 and it is being recreated constantly with last item.

This is file where I use session:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "hideSession",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: true,
        httpOnly: false,
    }
  }));
```

Whole `add_to_cart` route request:

```
app.post("/add_to_cart/:name", async (req, res) => {

    let db = await connect();
    let cursor = await db.collection("products").find({})
    let finalData = await cursor.toArray();
    const name= req.params.name;

    const singleDrink = await finalData.find((product) => product.name === name);
    let cart;
    if (!req.session.cart) req.session.cart = cart = new Cart({});

    else cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);

    req.session.cart = cart;
    cart.addDrink(singleDrink);
    console.log(req.session.cart,req.session.cookie)
    res.send(cart);
});
```

client side using axios:

```
let Cart = {
    addToCart(name){
            return Service.post(`/add_to_cart/${name}`)
        }
    }
```

client side passing function from axios:

```
async sendCartData(name){
                Cart.addToCart(name);
            }
```

And button:

```
<p @click="sendCartData(item.name)" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</p>
```

This is Cart file:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.products = oldCart.products || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0.00;
  
    this.addDrink = function(item) {
      let storeItem = this.products;
      if (!storeItem.hasOwnProperty("item")) {
        
        storeItem = this.products = {item: item};
        this.totalQty = 1;
        this.totalPrice = parseFloat(item.price);
  
      } else {
  
        storeItem = {item: item};
        this.products = storeItem;
        Object.defineProperties(storeItem, {
            currentQty: {
                enumerable: false,
                writable: true
            },
            price: {
                enumerable: false,
                writable: true
            }
        },
        
        );
        storeItem.currentQty++;
        storeItem.price = parseFloat(storeItem.item.price * storeItem.currentQty);
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice += parseFloat(storeItem.item.price);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand -- how are you running a session on the client side? It looks like there may be some code missing here that might help us understand the problem anyhow. Can you explain what you are seeing that leads you to believe the session is being recreated on the client side?

Comment: @Codebling I'm sorry, I didn't express myself correctly... I'm running session on server side, but when I test it with client side it is being recreated. For example cart of some items is at quantity of 1 regardless if I add 2 items or more. However it works on server side just fine.

Comment: I updated my question, so please take a look, hope things are clearer from now.

Comment: Ah ok! How are you testing on the server side? Unit tests? Maybe you can show your route for `add_to_cart`. This is likely not your problem, but `express-session` has this to say about `resave`: *it can create race conditions where a client makes two parallel requests to your server and changes made to the session in one request may get overwritten when the other request ends*

Comment: On the server side I'm testing it with tool named Postman. I updated question again and put code which contains the whole request of route ```add_to_cart```

Comment: Can we see the Postman request? How are you setting the cookie/session in Postman? Sorry for all of the questions without any help

Comment: @Codebling no problem at all! Added 2 screenshots of Postman. If you figure it out you can put it in answer as well!

Comment: @Codebling hey do you have any idea how to fix this? I'm still stuck with it

Comment: You've hardcoded the session id in Postman (Cookie: `connect.sid=`) and it seems to work... I wonder if a new session is being created in the browser every time? I would open dev tools and look through the requests to see if a new `connect.sid` cookie is being set. You could also confirm this by taking the opposite route, and, after adding an item to cart, throw the sid from your browser into Postman. A third way to confirm the sessions is to debug the session middleware and poke around in the session store.

Comment: I think it's also worth trying to turn off the `resave` session option.It's possible there's a race condition in the browser (which is impossible in Postman)

Comment: It still doesn't help, the same issue happens again.

Comment: Got anything else on your mind? feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: Did you confirm whether `connect.sid` is consistent in your browser requests?

Comment: How do you mean exactly? I can see ```connect.sid``` in my browser for each request intended for the session.

Comment: I just checked, if I add ```cookie: { secure: true}``` my server side is also being recreated while testing in Postman. What does that mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247458/discussion-between-codebling-and-jan-tudan).

Comment: Did you find any solution? Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory, so not sure that it is the problem you have.

You seem to use the default session storage which is MemoryStore. With this storage, if application restart due for example to an exception, session in memory are lost.

In this case, your test `if (!req.session.cart)` is true and then session is recreated.

To verify this check the error log.

and also change the session storage for a disk persist storage. You'll find a list here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores

If you want to have performance of an in memory storage AND security of a disk persist storage, take a look at loki.js which is in this list :https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-loki

Comment: How to check error log? Actually it is constantly recreating and it never comes to the else part. Also don't know what to specifically use from the documentation

Comment: how do you launch your server? node server.js? npm start? pm2?

Comment: I do it with ```npm run serve``` and this is for serve script (package.json): ```"serve": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js"```

Comment: Can this maybe be solved using ```localStorage``` in client side and how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

## Seems to work

I copied the code you've shared and ran it locally and it does appear to work. I tested by entering the path `/add_to_cart/:name` directly in the browser address bar. I was able to confirm that the cart numbers are incremented.

I was able to confirm also that Session ID is consistent across requests. If this is NOT the case with the rest of your code, then something is deleting your session and you'll need to troubleshoot that (respond in comments if so).

[image]

[image]

## Cart needs improvement

That being said, your cart logic seems extremely overcomplicated (making properties non-enumerable, reassigning variables to themselves) and somewhat broken. It is only able to track a single item, and `storeItem.currentQty` and `storeItem.price` are always `NaN`.
Your cart should keep an array of the added item IDs and the quantities of each. Here is an example implementation of a cart:

```
  items;
  constructor(oldCart) {
    this.items = oldCart?.items ?? [];
  }

  addDrink(item) {
    let cartItem = this.items.find(i => i._id == item._id);
    if (cartItem == null) {
      cartItem = {
        _id: item._id,
        qty: 0,
        unitPrice: parseFloat(item.price),
      };
      this.items.push(cartItem);
    }
    cartItem.qty++;
  }
  get totalQty() {
    return this.items.reduce( (totalQty, item) => totalQty += item.qty, 0);
  }
  get totalPrice() {
    return this.items.reduce( (totalPrice, item) => totalPrice += item.qty * item.unitPrice, 0.00);
  }
}
```

Note that in this implementation, the item descriptions are not cached and would have to be retrieved from the database if they are to be displayed - you may want to add a description in as needed.

Comment: Okay, so I tested it and again it does work in Postman and it is the same as it was before but while interacting with client side the quantity is again 1 no matter of requests. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Yes, literally identical

Comment: Wait what is identical ?

Comment: It is same as before, another value (session-id) per request

Comment: Did you put `/add_to_cart/:name` in address bar of browser

Comment: I put `http://localhost:8080/add_to_cart/test` in browser and it works. If you're getting a new session then the problem is not with any of the code that you posted, it's with other code.

Comment: I'm testing it (on client side) with click on a button: ```@click="sendCartData(item.name)"```

Comment: Test it with the `add_to_cart` directly in the address bar.

Comment: At this point, you have two (similar) options: 1) I can post the code I used to test on GitHub, and you can test on your end with that and start building your app from there, 2) you can remove all of the other routes and middleware until you have something that works, then start adding routes and middleware back until it breaks. That way you'll find the problem. Let me know if you'd like me to share my repo on GitHub.

Comment: Now I updated everything in my question what is included with this request (even on client side), unfortunatelly I cannot put it on Github, maybe later.

Comment: @JanTuđan, No, I said I could post the code on GitHub so you could try it on your end. Here it is https://github.com/codebling/so-73323888

Comment: Yes it works again on server side. But not testing it with client side as I said before. I'm using axios as a different service and trying to send data with my client side. So I think there is problem with axios or somehow include axios's ```withCredentials``` property because it may cause the problem of refreshing server side on each request and this could recreate the whole session, right?

Comment: @JanTuđan Server-side does not make sense to me in this context

Comment: All I was saying is that the express service is being refreshed on each client interaction so the data from cart will always be renewed. So I suppose that the problem is with axios service.

Comment: @JanTuđan sounds like you made some progress! Maybe open a new question with your client-side code?

Comment: Thank you! I will send you a link of a new question when I post it in an hour

Comment: I just added a new question related to this one, give it a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73470954/data-from-express-session-is-being-renewed-refreshed-on-each-request-when-using